# Any Open Source Fast Fourier Transform C implementation?

Tags: c

I'm trying to find the fundamental frequency of a recorded sound using FFT in C. Would anyone know a open source implementation in C that I can modify and use?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried typing "C FFT" in google and clicking the first link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/) is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm concerned in that the page calls this a discrete fourier transform with arbitrary input size. The fast fourier transform algorithm only supports inputs of size 2^n. The name "fastest fourier transform" may be confusing, and not imply the FFT algorithm (except perhaps as an optimisation when applicable).

Comment: @Steve314 FFT's of arbitrary dimensions can be computed. The power-of-two case happens to be the fastest and the easiest to implement, but fast algorithms exist to compute Fourier Transforms for any input size.

Comment: @Thomas - I had a long-standing belief that "fast fourier transform" was the name of a specific algorithm. Thanks for prompting me to check - I now see that what I called the FFT was actually the [Cooley-Tukey algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform#Algorithms) and as you say, there are more FFT algorithms than that.

Comment: FFTW is GPL'd, and a source license for commercial products is expensive.  Consider that carefully before using it.

Answer (score 6):

I've found [Ooura's C fft packages](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~ooura/fft.html) to be superior to FFTW's for practical purposes.  Using FFTW optimally takes time and patience to get FFTW's wisdom system working correctly, especially when cross-compiling.  Additionally, FFTW has that [viral GPL license](http://www.fftw.org/doc/License-and-Copyright.html) attached to it, so you can't use it in closed-source projects without paying them a bunch of money.

Unlike FFTW, Ooura's code has a very permissive license; additionally, Ooura's work doesn't depend on a complex build environment.  Other than FFTW, [Ooura's code is either the fastest, or nearly the fastest, cross-platform FFT library.](http://www.fftw.org/speed/)  It runs about twice as fast as the KISS FFT library, which remains popular for some inexplicable reason.  Ooura's code takes two-level CPU caches into account, which works well with most modern processors.

If you truly feel the need for speed, then you should skip FFTW and Ooura and go direct to your CPU manufacturer for their custom FFT libraries.  Vendor-supplied, CPU specific libraries tend to be the fastest in a footrace.  Some examples include [Intel MKL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-fortran-fourier-transform-functions) and [clFFT](https://github.com/clMathLibraries/clFFT).

Also, if you're trying to find fundamental frequencies, don't forget about good old fashioned autocorrelation.  If it works well enough for you it may be significantly faster than running an FFT.  Check out the [classic Rabiner paper](http://www.ece.ucsb.edu/Faculty/Rabiner/ece259/Reprints/110_autocorrelation%20pitch.pdf) for an overview.

Someone said they needed an FFT library that works with single-precision as well as double-precision floats.  [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#fft) can do this.  If you decide to use single-precision floats to calculate FFTs, BE COMPLETELY SURE that you have measured and quantified the amount of error in the results.  FFTs are a huge pile of multiplies, and roundoff errors can aggregate VERY quickly indeed with a single-precision FFT.  You can get results that look good but are wrong.  Consider yourself warned...

Comment: Can the Ooura FFT be used with arbitrary length FFTs ?

Comment: No, it's power of two limited like most other FFT libraries, use FFTW if you need arbitrary lengths.

Comment: I also note that the Ooura implementation is double only, I suppose replacing with float should be straight forward?

Comment: I don't recommend doing the double-to-float replacement.  Updated answer above.

Comment: Thanks John, I mainly want to use the FFT with FD convolution (audio filtering).

Comment: Then why do you care whether it is power of two limited?  And why are you trying to do it in float?

Comment: I see you're not an "audio guy" ;) 1. Power-o-2 FFTs typically are faster, and FD convolution usually is partitioned into several PO2 FFTs (to lower the latency). 2. Audio data typically comes in floats (for most if not all audio frameworks), so I'd like to avoid the overhead of copying floats to doubles. 3. Performance. Float usually has twice the speed over doubles due to SIMD.

Comment: The reason I asked if it can be used with arbitrary length data, is that I'd like also to use it as an FFT backend for Eigen, and I *believe* it is a requirement. Not sure though.

Comment: Use Armadillo, it's significantly faster than Eigen and works fine with foreign libraries like ooura.  And yes, I am an "audio guy," as you put it.  If you're trying to use weird-length FFTs for convolution, you're probably really wanting to zero-pad your windows to be a power of 2. As for floats vs. doubles in FFTs: you'll eventually figure that out too, either the easy way or the hard way.

Comment: Thanks John, interesting what you say about Armadillo, we use Eigen pretty extensively here (mainly as a way to port DSP code from Matlab to C++ with as close a syntax as possible). In what respect is it faster ? Do you know of any benchmarks ? Edit: Nevermind, I found some. Ok! Seems highly interesting! Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Also, if you're really doing convolution in the frequency domain on an audio tool, FFT based techniques introduce too much latency.  You'll need a low-latency fast convolution technique, like http://www.ericbattenberg.com/school/partconvDAFx2011.pdf .

Comment: Yup, that's the one I'm doing, i.e. with time-domain convolution for the first 128 samples or so, thanks for the info though.

Answer (score 2):

Another worth considering is [D.J. Bernstein's](http://cr.yp.to/djbfft.html). It's somewhat on the complex side (as is FFTW) but faster than most (including FFTW) in most tests.

Answer (score 1):

You will find here a C/C++ implementation, with a description of the source code (tutorial):
http://drdobbs.com/cpp/199500857

Comment: The question was for a C implementation - this is a C++ implementation using template metaprogramming. That said, listing one does give an FFT, taken from Numerical Recipes in C++, which is pretty close to being C (the "swap" calls don't exist in the C library IIRC, but that's easily fixed).

Answer (score 0):

An implementation using optimized bit-shifts can be found at [**XFT library of algorithms**](http://www.jjj.de/fxt/fxtpage.html). It is worth a look for more than just Fourier transforms.